# RadioButtonList won't change after doPostBack - ASP.NET JS C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a `radioButtonList` inside a `Panel`. The panel uses `UpdatePanel` to update its panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlTeacherDismissal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="tmrRefreshTeacher_OnTick">
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlDismissalTeacher" runat="server"; color:White; width:100%;">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnStatusDismissal" AutoPostBack="true"
                                runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbtnStatusDismissal_OnSelectedIndexChanged" >
      <asp:ListItem ID="id1" Text="In Class" Value="1" />
      <asp:ListItem ID="id2" Text="Dismiss" Value="4" />
      <asp:ListItem ID="id3" Text="Field Trip" Value="5" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The updatepanel refreshes every 5 seconds which is trigerred by Javascript function (I know there's timer from `System.Class.UI` but for some reason I have to use JS function). Here is the refresh function:

```
function refresh() {  
     //update teacher panel
     __doPostBack('<%=upnlTeacherDismissal.UniqueID%>', '');
}

setInterval(refresh, 5000);
```

When `doPostBack`, on behind code, I want to set the radio button value to the updated value from database but there's no any change from the UI (radiobutton value is still 1). The program will execute this function every 5 seconds (not from `rbtnStatusDismissal_OnSelectedIndexChanged`).

```
protected void tmrRefreshTeacher_OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    //... few lines to check the database if table changes 
    rbtnStatusDismissal.SelectedValue = (int)data.statusID; 
    //let's say (int)data.statusID equals 5
    upnlTeacherDismissal.Update();
}
```

I've tried to debug and see that .SelectedValue has been set to the value of the data.statusID (let's say 5). But the radio button's value in UI still equals 1 (instead of 5). 
What's wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its work perfectly for me you are missing something i edited and replace that

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlTeacherDismissal" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlDismissalTeacher" runat="server" style="color:White; width:100%;">
      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnStatusDismissal" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbtnStatusDismissal_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem ID="id1" Text="In Class" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem ID="id2" Text="Dismiss" Value="4" />
        <asp:ListItem ID="id3" Text="Field Trip" Value="5" />
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on server side

```
protected void rbtnStatusDismissal_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rbtnStatusDismissal.SelectedValue = "5";
    upnlTeacherDismissal.Update();            
}
```

and this js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() {  
           //update teacher panel
           __doPostBack('<%=upnlTeacherDismissal.UniqueID%>', '');
        }

    setInterval(refresh, 5000);
</script>
```

if you have any question and will not get answer then ask in comments.

Comment: I've added the closing tags of course, but still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: have you added content template inside updatepanel and also remove onload from update panel..@user2393874

Comment: yes but still no change, looks like the UI won't update

Comment: have you tried my code including the javascript function and the behind code?

Comment: yes i have tried your code and when i select any value then its value change it means id3 is selected. and have you added style attribute in your panel ? ..have you checked your console any error related that.@user2393874

Comment: every 5 seconds update panel refreshing using js function and its radio buttons value is as selected 5.@user2393874

Comment: i think you misunderstand my question, i've updated my post. look at tmrRefreshTeacher_OnTick

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49037/discussion-between-sumit-pathak-and-user2393874)

Comment: I've joined the conversation.